# Alternative to url_for in ActionController::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to pass a url to a background process so that it can post it on facebook/tweet it.

```
class Weeklychecks < ActionController::Base
.
.
.
   def self.verifications
   .
   .
   .
   @my_url = url_for(:action => 'show', :controller => 'profiles', :only_path => false)
   .
   end
end
```

But it seems that this code is deprecated: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for

I've used this method when the base class is ApplicationController, but I need to use ActionController::Base in this one. I've tried to add 
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
but it doesn't work either. Is there a workaround about this?

I'm running Rails 3.2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off `url_for` isn't deprecated. When code gets reorganised apidock sometimes interprets the fact that a method is no longer where it used to be as the method actually having been removed.

url_for and all the helper methods such as profile_url are included as instance methods, which is why you can't call them from your class method.

You should be able to do

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(...)
```

no matter where you are. The helpers like `profile_path` also live in here. If you're generating absolute urls you'll need to pass in tr host. Normally this is taken from the host of the request the controller is processing, but that is obviously not possible in this context.

Comment: Where can you find other helpers like link_to?

Answer (score 0):

If you have in your routes

```
resources :profiles
```

You can do

```
@my_url = profile_url(some_profile)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I do have resources :profiles and I'm still getting 'undefined method `profile_url' for Weeklychecks:Class (NoMethodError)' in the same way that before I was getting "undefined method `url_for' for Weeklychecks:Class (NoMethodError)"

I've tried adding "include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper" and still the same result.

Comment: Also, both methods work correctly when used on ProfilesController, it's just when I try to use them in a different controller.

Comment: This may seem silly but rename your controller to WeeklychecksController